# select query on one table with join on same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am bit in a struggle with a select query on one table but join 2 same columns together. To simplify my problem, I made a reconstruction of the situation. 
I got a table that looks like this:

```
declare @DummyTable Table 
(
    Id int, 
    MainName varchar(20), 
    SubName varchar(20), 
    sequenceNumber int
)
```

This table contains the next data:

```
insert into @DummyTable 
values ( 0, 'MainName1', 'SubName1', 1),
       ( 1, 'MainName1', 'SubName2', 2),
       ( 2, 'MainName1', 'SubName3', 3),
       ( 3, 'MainName1', 'SubName6', 4),
       ( 4, 'MainName1', 'SubName7', 5),
       ( 5, 'MainName2', 'SubName1', 1),
       ( 6, 'MainName2', 'SubName2', 2),
       ( 7, 'MainName2', 'SubName3', 3),
       ( 8, 'MainName2', 'SubName4', 4),
       ( 9, 'MainName2', 'SubName5', 5),
       (10, 'MainName2', 'SubName6', 6),
       (11, 'MainName2', 'SubName7', 7),
       (12, 'MainName3', 'SubName1', 1),
       (13, 'MainName3', 'SubName2', 2),
       (14, 'MainName3', 'SubName3', 3)
```

Now I try to get all the records containing the text MainName1 and on the same row I want also the records MainName2, matching by the SubName column, like this:

```
Id | MainName  | SubName  | s | Id | MainName  | SubName  | s -- s = SequenceNumber
--------------------------------------------------------------
 5 | MainName2 | SubName1 | 1 |  0 | MainName1 | SubName1 | 1
 6 | MainName2 | SubName2 | 2 |  1 | MainName1 | SubName2 | 2
 7 | MainName2 | SubName3 | 3 |  2 | MainName1 | SubName3 | 3
 8 | MainName2 | SubName4 | 4 | NULL | NULL    | NULL     | NULL
 9 | MainName2 | SubName5 | 5 | NULL | NULL    | NULL     | NULL
10 | MainName2 | SubName6 | 6 |  3 | MainName1 | SubName6 | 4
11 | MainName2 | SubName7 | 7 |  4 | MainName1 | SubName7 | 5
```

I try to manage this with the next query:

```
 select *
 from @DummyTable dt1
 left join @DummyTable dt2 on dt1.SubName = dt2.SubName
 where dt1.MainName like '%Name2%'
 and dt2.MainName like '%Name1%'
 order by dt1.MainName, dt1.sequenceNumber
```

But when I execute this query, I get the result I want but with records with the ids 8 and 9 missing. I tried to right join, or only join (without left or right) but all gives the same result, not showing records with the ids 8 and 9. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong here and I am also wondering why I am not seeing the missing records. Could anyone help me to understand my problem and how I can fix it?

Comment: If you want to filter right table in `left outer join` do it in `on` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
select *
from @DummyTable dt1
left join @DummyTable dt2 on dt2.SubName = dt1.SubName and dt2.MainName like '%Name1%'
where dt1.MainName like '%Name2%' --and (dt2.MainName like '%Name1%')
order by dt1.MainName, dt1.sequenceNumber
```

You lost `null` values because of your `where` clause where you filtered out records which do not match `dt2.MainName like '%Name1%'` from results.

Edit: my query was not quite working as `dt2` not always returned null for values to be missing, so I moved argument into join clause and now it is working as expected.

Comment: Thnx for the answer. I tried your query but it gives the same result, the record with ids 8 and 9 missing. Those null values I have lost, in the original table they aren't even there so how can I be lost? Or is the where clause applied after the left join which "creates" the null values I want to show at the records with ids 8 and 9?

Comment: Check my edit. It was not working as there is match for your `join` for every record, that's why checking for null was not enough.

Comment: Thank you very much, that query gives the result I want. Although I am not quite sure yet what went wrong in the first place. My guess is that the check on name1 in the where clause didnt generate the null rows for the left join?

Comment: Yes. Your left join returned match for every record but with `Name` like `MainName1` and `MainName3` (so there was no nulls) and then where clause filtered `MainName3` and so 2 rows were missing. Hopefully this makes sense :)